# what benefits does using @stateless in JAX-RS offer in Java EE 6 and above?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb, jax-rs, java-ee-6

I am going through the [TicketMonster tutorial](http://www.jboss.org/ticket-monster/datapersistence/) available with `JBoss` using Java EE 6.

Here are a couple of REST service classes I found in this tutorial.

```
@Path("/media")
public class MediaService {

    @Inject
    private MediaManager mediaManager;

    @Inject EntityManager entityManager;

    @GET
    @Path("/cache/{cachedFileName:\\S*}")
    @Produces("*/*")
    public File getCachedMediaContent(@PathParam("cachedFileName") String cachedFileName) {
        return mediaManager.getCachedFile(cachedFileName);
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/{id:\\d*}")
    @Produces("*/*")
    public File getMediaContent(@PathParam("id") Long id) {
        return mediaManager.getCachedFile(mediaManager.getPath(entityManager.find(MediaItem.class, id)).getUrl());
    }
}

@Path("/metrics")
@Stateless
public class MetricsService {

    @Inject
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<ShowMetric> getMetrics() {
        return retrieveMetricsFromShows(retrieveShows(),
            retrieveOccupiedCounts());
    }

    private List<ShowMetric> retrieveMetricsFromShows(List<Show> shows,
        Map<Long, Long> occupiedCounts) {
        List<ShowMetric> metrics = new ArrayList<ShowMetric>();
        for (Show show : shows) {
            metrics.add(new ShowMetric(show, occupiedCounts));
        }
        return metrics;
    }

    private List<Show> retrieveShows() {
        TypedQuery<Show> showQuery = entityManager
            .createQuery("select DISTINCT s from Show s JOIN s.performances p WHERE p.date > current_timestamp", Show.class);
        return showQuery.getResultList();
    }

    private Map<Long, Long> retrieveOccupiedCounts() {
        Map<Long, Long> occupiedCounts = new HashMap<Long, Long>();

        Query occupiedCountsQuery = entityManager
            .createQuery("select b.performance.id, SIZE(b.tickets) from Booking b "
                + "WHERE b.performance.date > current_timestamp GROUP BY b.performance.id");

        List<Object[]> results = occupiedCountsQuery.getResultList();
        for (Object[] result : results) {
            occupiedCounts.put((Long) result[0],
                ((Integer) result[1]).longValue());
        }

        return occupiedCounts;
    }
}
```

My question is why is `@stateless` not used in `MediaService` class but used in `MetricsService` class. but advantage that `MetricsService` class has (except that it can be injected being an EJB since it carries `@Stateless` annontation). But I browsed the entire the application code to see if `MetricsService` was injected but it never was.

Kindly point me why the authors used @Stateless in one but not the other.
Source code is available in this [github repo](https://github.com/jboss-developer/ticket-monster/tree/2.6.0.Final-with-tutorials/demo/src/main/java/org/jboss/jdf/example/ticketmonster/rest).

Answer (score 3):

Brain, I assume the developer either did not exactly knew what he does or some features are missing.
I've checked also the code the MetricService is only for analysing "performance metrics" of the business case. Since it is a simple REST service the @Stateless is useless in this case.

In some earlier Java EE 6 versions of jboss/wildfly, the injection of the EntityManager was not possible on REST services. You had to inject the EMFactory instead. 
So I assume either it is due to mentioned and not finished feature or some old reference to workaround the EntityManager injection...

The @Stateless is only needed if you need the EJB feature like Java EE Security on your REST service.

Comment: you would also need @Stateless if you want container managed transactions correct?

Comment: afaik yes. Checked the specification, but seems to be not fully clear specified there.
I always try to use EJBs for accessing the database. Since I always try to use the container's CMT.
So my REST-model/DTO classes are just passing the data to my EJBs which process the Entities and read/persist them

Comment: found something, which may help on your last question:
https://www.java.net/node/701498
So from the post it is the opposite of my last comment

Comment: even I currently do REST/DTO model with Java EE 5. since we are migrating to Java EE 6, which is capable of CDI in REST layer, we want to benefit from it..

Comment: At first glance I was thinking transaction management also, but there are only read operations being performed, so no transactions needed. I agree with the "useless in this case" part of this answer (+1). Might be something you need to ask the author himself.

Comment: @peeskillet: with Java EE6, there is no need of `@Stateless`. In either case, you get container managed transaction. https://www.java.net/node/701498. so why do you need it whether it is Read only or Read-write EJB operation..

Comment: @brainstorm This is not true what you are writing. Post you are referring to is incorrect. There is no container managed transactions in plain JAX-RS. You need EJB for that. Without `@Stateless` you may have JTA transaction, but you will need to manage it by yourself. It will not be managed by container. There is nothing in the JAX-RS specification that would say its resources are container managed.

Comment: @Gas: Thanks for pointing out. any documentation that supports your view here would be helpful. since the above post is from java.net, it could be very much legitimate